# Como criar paralelismo em uma multithreading específica?

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

**O meu cenário é o seguinte:**

> Simular um tanque de água associado a duas torneiras: uma usada para
>   encher o tanque e outra usada para esvaziar o tanque.

**Regras:**

> a) A capacidade total do tanque é de 2000 litros e cada "bolinha" representa 10 litros.
>
> b) A torneira que enche o tanque tem uma vazão de 10 litros a cada 150 ms
>   (milissegundos).
>
> c) A torneira que esvazia o tanque tem uma vazão de 30 litros a cada 150 ms
>   (milissegundos).
>
> d) O controlador do tanque é responsável por abrir e fechar as torneiras.
>   e) Quando o tanque atinge seu volume máximo, a torneira de enchimento é fechada e a torneira de esvaziamento é aberta.
>
> f) Quando o tanque estiver abaixo de 50% do seu volume a torneira de enchimento deverá ser aberta.
>
> g) Quando o volume de água ficar abaixo da torneira de esvaziamento, essa torneira deverá ser fechada.

**O meu problema:**

> Como faço para que a torneira de enchimento (faucetA) e torneira de
>   esvaziamento (faucetB) tenham um paralelismo de acordo com a minha
>   regra de negócios?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TankController tc = new TankController();
        tc.start();
    }

}

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Tank {
    private final int maximumCapacity = 2000;
    private int volumeOfWater;
    private boolean empty;
    private BigDecimal percentageOfWater;

    public int getVolumeOfWater() {
        return volumeOfWater;
    }

    public void setVolumeOfWater(int volumeOfWater) {
        if (this.exceededMaximumVolume(volumeOfWater))
            this.volumeOfWater = 2000;
        else
            this.volumeOfWater += volumeOfWater;
    }

    private boolean exceededMaximumVolume(int volumeOfWater) {
        return (this.getVolumeOfWater() + volumeOfWater > 2000) ? true : false;
    }

    public double getPercentageOfWater() {
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(this.maximumCapacity);
        BigDecimal rate  = new BigDecimal(this.getVolumeOfWater());
        BigDecimal percentage = rate.divide(value).multiply(new BigDecimal("100"));

        return percentage.doubleValue();
    }

}


public class Faucet extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private int waterFlow;

    public Faucet(String name, int waterFlow) {
        this.name = name;
        this.waterFlow = waterFlow;
    }

    public int getWaterFlow() {
        return this.waterFlow;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        switch(this.name) {
            case "faucetA":
                System.out.println("TORNEIRA DE ENCHER ABERTA.. ENCHENDO O TANQUE!");
            case "faucetB":
                System.out.println("TORNEIRA DE ENCHER FECHADA..");
                System.out.println("TORNEIRA DE VAZÃO ABERTA.. ESVAZIANDO O TANQUE!");
        }
    }

}

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TankController extends Thread {
    private Tank tank = new Tank();
    private final Faucet faucetA = new Faucet("faucetA", 10);
    private final Faucet faucetB = new Faucet("faucetB", 30);

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        this.faucetA.start();
        this.faucetB.start();

        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(this.tank.getPercentageOfWater() + "%");

                if(this.tank.getPercentageOfWater() < 100) {
                    this.faucetA.sleep(150);
                    this.tank.setVolumeOfWater(this.faucetA.getWaterFlow());
                } else if(this.tank.getPercentageOfWater() == 100) {
                    System.out.println("TANQUE NA CAPACIDADE MÁXIMA..\n");
                    this.faucetB.sleep(150);
                    this.tank.setVolumeOfWater(this.tank.getVolumeOfWater() - this.faucetB.getWaterFlow());
                } else if (this.tank.getPercentageOfWater() < 50) {
                    System.out.println("TANQUE ABAIXO DA METADE DA CAPACIDADE..\n");
                    this.faucetA.sleep(150);
                    this.tank.setVolumeOfWater(this.faucetA.getWaterFlow());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No método run da classe Facet faltou colocar break no switch case.

```
switch(this.name) {
        case "faucetA":
            System.out.println("TORNEIRA DE ENCHER ABERTA.. ENCHENDO O TANQUE!");
            break;
        case "faucetB":
            System.out.println("TORNEIRA DE ENCHER FECHADA..");
            System.out.println("TORNEIRA DE VAZÃO ABERTA.. ESVAZIANDO O TANQUE!");
 }
```

Também tem de colocar uma paragem, se não irá dar stackoverflow no `while(true)`

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. A minha pergunta foi especificamente a Multithread e paralelismo. De acordo com as Regras de negócios citadas acima, como eu faço para manipular corretamente as torneiras (faucets) ? Eu sinto que o meu método Run da classe TankController está incorreta a manipulação destas threads. Caso resposta eu darei ponto para a sua pergunta.

Comment: podia explicar o ponto g) ? Como assim menor que a torneira de esvaziamento? Quando o tanque tiver menos que 30 lt?

Comment: quando o tanque estiver em < 50% a torneira de esvaziamento será fechada e a torneira de encher será aberta.

Comment: Porque usou BigDecimal? Aqui os números não vão além de 2000 e não exigem o uso dessa classe.

Comment: utilizei para poder gerar a percentagem de litros no tanque.